# Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'

Tags: mongodb

[image]
.> mongo

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-06-26T17:37:13.313+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 127.0.0.1:27017
2018-06-26T17:37:13.313+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: SocketException socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
2018-06-26T17:37:13.313+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Mongod logs to find the root cause. For me it was leaking connections from one of the clients, this is what I found in logs:

`NETWORK  [listener] connection refused because too many open connections:`

Answer (score 14):

This problem can happen when trying to connect to a database which requires SSL.

Answer (score 10):

This error is usually caused by attempting to connect without SSL to a MongoDB server that requires it. Use the following command to connect:

```
mongo --ssl --username "$USERNAME" --password "$PASSWORD" --host "$HOST" --port  "$PORT"
```

Answer (score 3):

(SSL causing the issue)
You can connect with it using this command :

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --tls --username fake --password fakepassword --authenticationDatabase admin --sslAllowInvalidHostnames
```

> Disables the validation of the hostnames in TLS/SSL certificates.
> Allows mongo to connect to MongoDB instances even if the hostname in
> their certificates do not match the specified hostname.
>
> Deprecated since version 4.2: Use --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames instead.

**WARNING :**

> Although available, avoid using the --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
> option if possible. If the use of --sslAllowInvalidCertificates is
> necessary, only use the option on systems where intrusion is not
> possible.
>
> If mongosh (and other MongoDB Tools) runs with the
> --sslAllowInvalidCertificates option, mongosh (and other MongoDB Tools) will not attempt to validate the server certificates. This
> creates a vulnerability to expired mongod and mongos certificates as
> well as to foreign processes posing as valid mongod or mongos
> instances. If you only need to disable the validation of the hostname
> in the TLS/SSL certificates, see --sslAllowInvalidHostnames.

[See MongoDB official Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/)

Answer (score 0):

1. just go simply on task manager and click on service

see given image below to copy the link on the URL
[image]

2. find MongoDB and click on open Service.

see given image below to copy the link on the url
[image]

3. then again find MongoDB and start stopped DB to running mode just click on green point button and you MongoDB is again started connecting.

[see given image below to copy the link on the url]

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I was running several applications on other ports. The above solutions did not worked well for me .
Finally I closed all the tabs of code editor and web-app , and restarted it . Now it works fine .

Well! You can just restart the system, that will also work with least hassle.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this can happen because the server requires TLS in the connection. You will see the reason in server logs.

For someone who ends here without knowing how to fix it (like me) it's worth noting how to connect to those servers:

In command line you can use the --tls option (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/)

`mongo --tls [other params and/or connection string]`

If using a connection string alone, you can add `tls=true` param:

`mongo://[user]:[pass]@[host]/[db]?tls=true[&others]`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error in the mongod logs that read

```
WiredTiger metadata corruption detected
```

To fix the error I did the following:

1. As per suggestion [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) I ran command `mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair`.
2. The logs from command above complained that my version of mongod was too recent (I was on 4.2.x) and I had to try on mongod 4.2 or earlier.
3. Downgraded to mongod 4.2
4. Ran command `mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair` again, and this fixed issue.

I do run mongod inside Docker, so I had to take an extra step to find out path of the mongo DB file, `docker inspect <id of mongod container>`, and grab the path from the `HostConfig.Binds[0]` property of the resulting JSON, and stick that in the `--dbpath` option of the repair command `mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is `net.maxIncomingConnections: 10` in the config file and `MongoDB Compass`.

All available connection slots the server has, are consumed by other clients and that causes new connection requests to just drop.

I was not aware that Compass would open so many connections. When I closed it, my problem was solved.

The default connection limit is 65536 as stated in [config options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.maxIncomingConnections)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens but sometimes my mongo instance fails to start properly. Just shutting it down and restarting it worked for me.